# Capture jpgs produced in subprocess in main script

Tags: python, image, pdf, thumbnails, stdout

I'm not sure that this is possible, but I'm trying to generate a number of thumbnails from pdfs in an automated way and then store them within elasticsearch. Basically I would like to convert the pdf to a series of jpgs (or pngs, or anything similar) and then index them as binaries. Currently I'm producing these jpgs like this:

```
import subprocess
params = ['convert', 'pdf_file', 'thumb.jpg']
subprocess.check_call(params)
```

which works well, but it just writes the jpgs out to the filesystem. I would like to have these files as strings without writing them out to the local file system at all. I've tried using the stdout methods of subprocess, but I'm fairly new to using subprocesses, so I wasn't able to figure this one out.

I'm using imagemagick for this conversion, but I am open to switching to any other tool so long as I can achieve this goal.
Any ideas?

Comment: as you're working in python, it'd be a good idea to do it using python and not by calling an external program, forks tend to be expensive.

Comment: @zmo Forks may be expensive, but I'm doing this a few times with pretty large pdfs, so I imagine that the gain from not binding through python is worth it. Also I don't believe that subprocess actually forks.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: `subprocess` definitely forks (unless you're on Windows, in which case it `CreateProcess`es instead). How else could it work?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: PS, what platform are you on where forks are expensive? They're blazingly fast on linux, and fast enough that it rarely matters on OS X and other modern *BSDs.) Usually the exec and the link loader and so on take much longer than the fork (although still not nearly as long as Windows' CreateProcess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it send the data to stdout instead...

```
import subprocess
params = ['convert', 'pdf_file', 'jpg:-']
image_data = subprocess.check_output(params)
```

Comment: Oh, fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you can use imagemagick's [python API](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/), for example something like:

```
import PythonMagick

img = PythonMagick.Image("file.pdf")
img.depth = 8
img.magick = "RGB"
data = img.data
```

or use [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/):

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='file.pdf') as img:
    data = img.make_blob('png')
```

Comment: It appears that PythonMagick is no longer active.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: For traditional ImageMagick, PythonMagick still works. For the newer, higher-level MagickWand API, use PythonMagickWand instead. Or use Wand, which wraps up the lower-level API in the style of the higher-level one. (zmo's answer already has an example with `wand` alongside the `PythonMagic` one.) Or just go to [the APIs page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) and look over what's currently there. (You may also want to check PyPI.)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have these files as strings without writing them out to the local file system at all.

The way to do this is to tell the command to write its data to stdout instead of a file, then just read it from `proc.stdout`.

Not every command has a way to tell it to do this, but in many cases, just passing `-` as the output filename will do it, and that's true for ImageMagick's `convert`. Of course you'll also need to give it a format, because it can no longer guess it from the extension of `thumb.jpg`. The easiest way to do this is in `convert` is to prefix the type to the `-` pseudo-filename. (Don't try that with anything other than `ImageMagick`.)

So:

```
import subprocess
params = ['convert', 'pdf_file', 'jpg:-']
converted = subprocess.check_output(params)
```

However, this is going to get you one giant string. If you were trying to get a bunch of separate images, you'll need to split the one giant string into separate images, which will presumably require some knowledge of the JPEG/JFIF format.

Comment: Split into? Awaiting the conclusion.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: Oops, sorry. Fixed now.